# My mice (seems to be) not working correctly

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

So, recently, my mice is not working correctly. I've doubted that it has just got broken, so I bought another mouse, to fix the issue - however, it seems to be it isn't because of my mouse.

The symptom is that the device suddenly stops accepting any operation while in use. So, I suspected that there might be a disconnection, and checked the device manager, but it seems that there is no disconnection. By the way, both the mouse I had originally and the newly purchased mouse are wired ones, so it's not an error specific to the wireless connection type. Of course, I have installed the drivers correctly.

I also checked the event viewer to see if there were any errors, but there were no related errors or warnings.

Since I installed the OS in April of this year, I don't really think that there is something wrong with the OS. In fact, I can say that I have been using it very comfortably without any noticeable problems other than this one.

So I thought that maybe the USB port was malfunctioning. Fortunately, my motherboard has a large number of USB ports, so I tried several, but the result was the same. And it's only the mouse that gives me problems. I have other keyboards, USB microphones, Xbox controllers, keyboards (of musical instruments), and audio interfaces connected, and I haven't had any problems with all of them. Plugging something else into the port that causes the problem when using the mouse didn't cause any problems either.

I can no longer figure out what is going on. What could be going on to make this happen?

Comment: Could it be that the mouse is not working on a specific table surface?

Comment: @Hardoman No, I don't think so, since they're on mousepad that is created by the maker of the mouse(both of them, specifically SteelSeries Ten and SteelSeries Sensei 310 on SteelSeries QcK Limited+.) Plus, as I wrote in OP, -*suddenly stops accepting any operation*-, not only just moving cursor, they does not accept clicking, scrolling, etc. Maybe I should write it in the OP but their LED doesn't go away, it still emits its light.

Comment: If LED emits the light then USB port should be OK. I can only suggest try running WindowsPE or similar OS that doesn't require installation from boot media and check the behavior there. I suspect it's still OS issue.

Comment: @Hardoman Hmm. I'll try it on my Mac and Surface to see if it does the same(I assume they won't.) If it's OS issue, I guess the only way to fix is clean install the OS?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Appreciate your suggestion but, how are you certain that this is OS problem?

Comment: @Skye-AT, **if** it is the OS, first use DISM and SFC to attempt repair -- see https://www.thewindowsclub.com/dism-vs-sfc-first-windows-10 . It's less disruptive than reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you. Sadly both couldn't fix the problem, so I've clean installed OS(well, I was planning to do this on January anyway, so it's OK from me.) I'll take a time to see if it consists.